# Duplicate identifier 'PropertyKey' on @types/core-js dependency is installed

Tags: typescript

I'm getting these messages from webpack:

```
ERROR in [default] D:\projects\living\user-platform\project\node_modules\@types\core-js\index.d.ts:21:13
Duplicate identifier 'PropertyKey'.

ERROR in [default] D:\projects\living\user-platform\project\node_modules\@types\core-js\index.d.ts:85:4
All declarations of 'name' must have identical modifiers.

ERROR in [default] D:\projects\living\user-platform\project\node_modules\@types\core-js\index.d.ts:145:4
Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable '[Symbol.unscopables]' must be of type '{ copyWithin
: boolean; entries: boolean; fill: boolean; find: boolean; findIndex: boolean; keys: ...', but here has type 'any'.
```

I'm using a private package it's using `types/core-js` package as dev dependency.

So, I need to add it as dev dependency in my project as well. Nevertheless, it dumps me those messages.

Any ideas?

I've solved it using [this](http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/03/28/ambient-type-definitions-duplicate-identifier-typescript-fix/)

Nevertheless, I don't quite understand what am I doing wrong in fact...